# How to ng-model a text in a editable DIV rendered with ng-bind-html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind-html

I am rendering HTML text in a div, which I make then editable. The user can modify the text, but is there a way to get back the text modified in HTML?

This is the fiddle I am trying to make working:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Hello, {{name}}!
<div class="editable" ng-bind-html="documentBody"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'Superhero';
            $scope.documentBody = '<p align="center"><font size="2">Ciao</font></p><br><p align="center"><font size="2">Bello!</font></p>';
            $('.editable').each(function () {
                this.contentEditable = true;
            });
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sirfabio80/5sr8wnzv/

Thanks in advance
Fabio

Comment: Tbh I'd ask why you're bothering with ng-bind-html? Why not write a partial html file, and use ng-include? Then you can access the pieces you want as you normally would in a controller.

Comment: Because that html represent in my data model the body of a document template which a user needs to edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directive like below. We can't edit like you expect, We must use ng-model with some kind of simple way.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.names = [{name:"Ciao"},{name:"Bello"},{name:"Allo"}];           
});
myApp.directive('dirNew', function(){
return {
restrict:"EA",
scope:{repeats:"=",},
template:'<p align="center" ng-repeat="n in repeats"><span size="2" ng-click="click($index)" ng-hide="n.enabled">{{n.name}}</span><input type="text" ng-show="n.enabled" ng-model="n.name"><button ng-show="n.enabled" ng-click="click($index)">Ok</button></p><br>',
link: function(scope) {
      scope.click = function(index){
      scope.repeats[index].enabled = !scope.repeats[index].enabled; 
      }
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{names}}
<br>
  Hello, {{name}}!<br>
  Click the text and Edit......
  <dir-new repeats="names"></dir-new>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Manikandan!